# Is it possible to parse Json in build.sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt

I want to validate a downloaded Json file from server during build time and failed the build, if there are any errors.

Is it possible to parse/validate Json in build.sbt?

Answer (score 4):

Your build.sbt is scala code so it can do everything you can do with other scala code.

You should be able to add dependencies (e.g. a json parsing library) of your build.sbt code in project/build.sbt since [sbt is recursive](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Organizing-Build.html).

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example to supplement Jasper-M's answer.

For example, add liahoy's `requests-scala` HTTP client library, and `upickle` JSON deserialisation library to `project/builds.sbt`

```
libraryDependencies ++= List(
  "com.lihaoyi" %% "requests" % "0.6.0",
  "com.lihaoyi" %% "upickle" % "1.1.0"
)
```

Then under `project/Preconditions.scala` add the following object which will contain assertions you want to check before running the build

```
object Preconditions {
  import scala.util.Try
  import requests._
  import upickle.default._

  case class User(login: String, id: Int)
  implicit val userRW: ReadWriter[User] = macroRW

  def validateUserJson() = {
    val result = Try(read[User](get("https://api.github.com/users/lihaoyi").text)).isSuccess
    assert(result, "User JSON should be valid")
  }
}
```

Now these facilities will be available to `build.sbt` under the root project. Lets create a task in `build.sbt` to run the assertions

```
lazy val checkPreconditions = taskKey[Unit]("Validate pre-conditions before building")
checkPreconditions := {
  Preconditions.validateUserJson()
  println("All preconditions passed!")
}
```

and finally lets make `compile` task dependant on `checkPreconditions` task using `dependsOn` like so

```
Compile / compile := (Compile / compile).dependsOn(checkPreconditions).value
```

Now executing `sbt compile` should check pre-conditions before proceeding with compilation.